# New Oracle connection cannot be made

Tags: oracle

Our Oracle is 9i.

Recently we have faced a problem such that new connection cannot be made to Oracle while the ready-connected clients are working properly with Oracle.

After checking in Oracle log, we found the following error.
skgpspawn failed:category = 27143, depinfo = 9261, op = spdcr, loc = skgpspawn

After googled this error and we know that it is due to OS resource limitation.

In fact, what is the exact meaning of this error? mean the OS (Windows server 2003 in our case) does not have enough memory to process? Or the Oracle does not have enough memory to process?

What resource Oracle listener requires when it receive a client's request for making Oracle connection?

Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: Google also suggests it's a bug fixed in 9.2.0.3 (so which exact version are you on?) and with a workaround setting `SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME = 0`. Looking up the issue in My Oracle Support will give you more information.

Comment: Our version is 9.2.0.8 and we have not set SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME in server. In fact when Oracle would like to accept a new connection, how many  kbytes is required from system memory? what is the usage of this required memory? thx